# Is Workbooks a Class or Collection in VBA Excel?

Tags: excel, vba

what is the difference between Class and collection ? I am asking this I need to understand because in object browser "Workbooks" is a class , while it fulfills the property of a collection .

Comment: Collection is a class.

Comment: In a general sense a class is a blueprint for an object, and a collection is an object (an instance of a class)